# How to edit the fields in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Where is the `.php` file located to edit the billing fields?

I want to change the text for each heading; for example `Last Name` to `Family Name`.

This is using `Woocommerce in the Avada` theme.

I've managed to change the fields using this code, but city, state and postcode won't change:

```
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
$fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['label'] = '名';
$fields['billing']['billing_last_name']['label'] = '姓'; 
$fields['billing']['billing_email']['label'] = 'メールアドレス';
$fields['billing']['billing_phone']['label'] = '電話番号';
$fields['billing']['billing_country']['label'] = '国';
$fields['billing']['billing_city']['label'] = '名!';
$fields['billing']['billing_city']['placeholder'] = '市町村';
$fields['billing']['billing_state']['label'] = '都道府県';
$fields['billing']['billing_state']['placeholder'] = '都道府県';
$fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['label'] = '郵便番号';
$fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['placeholder'] = '郵便番号';
$fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['label'] = '住所';
$fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['placeholder'] = '住所';
$fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['placeholder'] = 'アパート名等';
return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try increase your priority used:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_override_checkout_fields', 50 );
```

Comment: Thanks I tried. It shows for a second then reverts back.

Comment: It could be a conflict in that case - my suggestion would be to at least try the code with just WooCommerce + no other plugins active and a default theme.